# VueJS: Can't update progress loader during rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, progress-bar, vue-reactivity

I am having a Vue app which is loading up to 15 different pivot tables with a lot of data.

The entire rendering time takes about 15 seconds.

Within this time period I really would like to display a progress bar up 100 %.

But unfortunately i can't update the progress bar during the rendering.

It is somehow blocked.

Which recommendations do you have to solve this issue?

The code looks like:

```
   <template
          v-for="n in (numberOfPivotTables - 1)"
      >
        <!-- Pivot table #1: spot count / ad count -->
        <mdb-col
          sm="12"
          md="12"
          lg="6"
          xl="6"
          :key="n"
        >

          <div class="pt-5 mx-3 pb-5 pr-5">

            <div style="height:350px">
              <h5>{{customPivotOptions[n]['reducerKey']}}</h5>

              <channel-filters
                :hour-options="filters.hour[n]"
                :adtype-options="filters.adType[n]"
                :length-options="filters.spotLength[n]"
                :creative-options="filters.motive[n]"
                :weekday-options="filters.weekday[n]"
                :flight-options="filters.flightId[n]"
                :month-options="filters.month[n]"
                :product-options="filters.product[n]"
                :station-options="filters.station[n]"
                :pivot-table-id="String(n)"
                @getValue="getSelectValue"
              >
              </channel-filters>

              <mdb-row>
                <mdb-col
                  cols="12"
                  sm="2"
                >
                  <mdb-select selectAll search 
                    @getValue="setReducerKey" 
                    :options="customPivotOptions[n].reducerOptions"
                    label="Value" 
                    :arrayId="String(n)"
                    modelName="reducerKey"
                    :visibleOptions="10"
                    placeholder="Choose your Value" /> 
                </mdb-col>
              </mdb-row>
            </div>

            <pivot-table
                :headline="customPivotOptions[n]['reducerKey']"
                :data="pivotData[n].data"
                :pivot-table-id="String(n)"
                :fields="fields[n]"
                :available-field-keys="customPivotOptions[n].availableFieldKeys"
                :row-field-keys="customPivotOptions[n].rowFieldKeys"
                :col-field-keys="customPivotOptions[n].colFieldKeys"
                :default-show-settings="defaultShowSettings"
                :reducer="getReducerKey"
                @getValues="getPivotValues"
                :sum-row="true"
                :sum-column="true"
                :sum-column-custom="{}"
                >
            </pivot-table>

          </div>

        </mdb-col>

            <div v-if="n==7" v-bind:key="n" class="w-100"></div>

      </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vue rendering is JS execution. When JS is executing, browser is not rendering (updating screen) so app looks frozen.

The way around it is simply do not render everything at the same time. `requestAnimationFrame` API can be very useful here. The code below is based on the [9 Performance Secrets Revealed](https://youtu.be/5B66qer8cZo?t=706) talk by with Guillaume Chau (Vue core team member) ([GitHub repo with code](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-9-perf-secrets))

1st we create a reusable mixin (factory function returning the mixin):
`defer.js`

```js
export default function (count = 10) {
  // @vue/component
  return {
    data () {
      return {
        displayPriority: 0,
      }
    },

    mounted () {
      this.runDisplayPriority()
    },

    methods: {
      runDisplayPriority () {
        const step = () => {
          requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            this.displayPriority++
            if (this.displayPriority < count) {
              step()
            }
          })
        }
        step()
      },

      defer (priority) {
        return this.displayPriority >= priority
      },
    },
  }
}
```

This mixin adds `displayPriority` counter to your component. It starts at 0 and is increased every time browser is ready to render new frame (repaint the screen) until it reaches `count` (passed as an argument to the factory function - default 10).

Important part is `defer()` function. It simply compares it's argument with `displayPriority` and returns true/false. For example `defer(2)` returns `false` when the browser repaints the screen for the 1st time (after component was rendered) and `true` for the rest of the page lifetime.

So the component with `v-if="defer(2)"` will be rendered (for the 1st time) before the component with `v-if="defer(3)"` etc.

Now it is easy to "split" the rendering of the parts of the component into multiple stages:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="n in (numberOfPivotTables - 1)">
 
      <heavyComponent v-if="defer(n)" :key="n" />

    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Defer from 'defer'

export default {
  mixins: [
    Defer(),  // pass number of steps as an argument. Default is 10
  ],
}
</script>
```

Comment: Levy
Thank you very much!
For me defer(i) is not 100 % clear. 
What exactly does the parameter " i " mean?
Inside the video Guillaume Chau mentions that the argument " i " is a frame.
But why exactly is he using the values 2 and 3 for " i "?
Looking into the definition of the mixin it seems like requestAnimationFrame (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is used.

Comment: @Levy
I ve also implemented the mixin but i don't see any performance improvement so far.

Comment: Number passed to the `defer()` is more or less "at which frame (from the time component is rendered for a 1st time) this component should become visible"

Comment: It works - [live demo](https://vue-9-perf-secrets.netlify.app/bench/deferred)

Comment: Hmm, 
I ve added the code in the following way and i don't get any loading improvements, yet:

`<template
    v-for="(n, i) in (numberOfPivotTables - 1)"
>
    <template v-if="defer(i)">
        <mdb-col>
        </mdb-col>

        <div v-if="n==7" v-bind:key="n" class="w-100"></div>
    </template>
</template>`

Comment: My original code was wrong (like iterating over array) - use `v-for="n in (numberOfPivotTables - 1)"` and `defer(n)`

Comment: yeah, i also tried it with this approach but the loading time is probably just 1 second less. 
It takes 14 seconds to load the tables.

Comment: This is not something to improve performance of your app. It is to make it more responsive and not look like it freezes fo 15 seconds. Also you asked "How to display progress bar?" This is the way because it splits long running operation into multiple steps and allows browser to repaint...

Comment: yes, you are right. 
But nevertheless the screen gets freezed.

Comment: Well then you are doing something wrong. The live demo page I linked proves this technique works...